# Managing branches in software version control

Tags: version-control, branch

I work on a software code base which goes into similar platforms. The platforms differ in hardware and in some software features but the large chunk of software is common. What is the best way to manage such a software project in version control system? If I create multiple branches based on each platform then I have to make sure I do multiple commits into each applicable branches. How do I maintain these branches? How do I comply to "single source of truth" philosophy? Aren't branches primarily for bug, feature development etc. that eventually get merged to mainline?

Answer (score 4):

Rearrange your projects such that you have your common code in one directory (or set of files), and your platform-specific code in its own files/directories. In other words, make a logical separation of this code in a single codebase.

Branches will be a rapid descent into madness and really aren't a good way to make this separation in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, but the platform specific code blocks are inseparable from common code. There are #ifdef in common code that is entangled with common code in places. So files/directory separation isn't possible. I understand the madness and want to find a better way to manage this chaos.

Comment: The better way to manage the chaos is to refactor your code so that it's not intermingled. One-time pain vs. a lifetime of pain.

Comment: Well, it kind of goes both ways. If the platform specific stuff is things like making sure that a given data type is a certain bit width across multiple platforms, it should be in the same place. If a given routine is the same in all but 2-3 lines, it should be in the same file. If you have to get information in a completely different way (getting user credentials on windows vs getting them on Unix, for example) then the "platform specific files" option makes more sense. And in neither case do you want to branch -- since it makes fixing common-code bugs harder.

Comment: I want to avoid branching. My ideal goal is to have just one dev branch apart from default trunk. Once the feature is ready for shipping, after testing I shall merge it to trunk. Trunk will have feature level atomic checkins. I am caught with "if ain't broken don't fix it" Dilemma. I agree spending some time refactoring the code will benefit in long run. We won't face problems of missed commits, partial feature, maintenance etc.